# python rpm module not available in python3

Tags: python, rpm, python3

I know python2 have a module named "rpm" that help in manipulating rpm databases,
as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51258124/20223973.

I see that module is not available in python3.

is there is any way I can install it ?

If that one deprecated is there is any other similar module in python3 ?
I'm looking for solution to find installed rpms directly from rpm db, not using linux 'rpm' utility.

Can someone please also direct me to source code of rpm module (just curious)

I'm using oracle linux box.

Comment: You haven't said anything about your operating system. The availability of the Python 3 rpm module depends on a particular distro and whether it uses Python 3 by default.

Comment: thanks @DanilaVershinin, just updated question

Comment: still you haven't provided the version of the distro in question. Things vary greatly per distro version.